# How to make sqlite robust over a Windows shared drive

Tags: sqlite

I know it is not recommend to use Sqlite over a network drive, for two reasons: performance, and data corruption due to bad implementation of network file systems.

Still, I'd like to explore the possibility of using Sqlite to support a multi-user application with a central database.  We already support Sqlite on a single-user machine and several database servers (Oracle, PostgreSQL) for multi-user setups.  Using Sqlite for multi-user setup would be convenient to allow lightweight installations on existing IT infrastructures with Windows shared drives (SMB).

We don't care too much about performance, so we are ready to pay the price needed to avoid corruption. Quoting http://www.sqlite.org/atomiccommit.html, section 9.1:

> But if you must use a network filesystem to store SQLite database
>   files, consider using a secondary locking mechanism to prevent
>   simultaneous writes to the same database even if the native filesystem
>   locking mechanism malfunctions.

I'm looking on hints and advices to implement such a mechanism, or, more generally, on tips to avoid problems with Sqlite over a Windows shared drive.

For instance, I'm considering the following brain-dead approach to locking: before any (non read-only) SQLite query, try to create an empty file on the same shared folder and keep it open until the end of the query; normally, any other Windows process trying to create a file with the same name while it's still open would block or fail. Would that work?  Anything better?

Comment: SQLite is not a replacement for a database server.

Comment: I know that, and as I said, we already support several kinds of database servers for our application.  We sell a business application; our users always have shared drives readily available, but having to rely on their IT and DBA teams to create and administrate, say, an Oracle instance for a small setup with 2-10 users is hugely expensive for them. We're just looking for something more lightweight to simplify deployment (for testing or even production).

Comment: Can't you just open the file for a non-shared read/write? Presumably each client app has it's own copy of the data, so it just means they won't be able to get an updated copy while another client is updating the database. You could end up with a lot of waiting around but it should work if the database is not too big.

Answer (score 2):

Another suggestion would be to write an API that sits over the SQLite file and does the locking for you.