# How can I use sqlite3 database on a network share drive?

Tags: c++, windows, sqlite

I am writing a time tracking Windows application in C++ that uses [sqlite3 engine](https://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html) to store its data. For my purpose it would be nice to share the database file across the local network (in a Windows network share folder) among several copies of my application, so that multiple users of the software could share data.

Is there a mechanism to do that with SQLite?

Comment: Should be able to use a UNC path.  Are you having a problem?

Comment: @RickS: That's what I thought. But before I start implementing it, I was making sure that it's supported. I heard that NTFS has a somewhat buggy file locking on a network share.

Comment: "With great bravery" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436564/how-to-make-sqlite-robust-over-a-windows-shared-drive , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788517/sqlite-over-a-network-share , https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html , https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html

Comment: You should include any research you have done and concerns you have in your original post.  We're not mind readers :-)

Comment: Why not use a proper client/server database that works across a network such as MySQL?

Comment: @MarkSetchell: Because I already have C++ code written for sqlite.

Comment: Maybe you can use a distributed lock mechanism to provide mutually exclusive access to your sqlite3 database... http://hoyvinglavin.com/2012/04/29/redis-as-a-mutex-service/ ... and ... http://redis.io/topics/distlock

Answer (score 1):

"nice to share the database file across the local network" You really don't want to do that. It will end up being more trouble than it's worth. In ideal circumstances it works, although the performance sucks a bit. In non-ideal circumstances, it will block forever without giving you any idea why and what's at fault.

It's much easier to partition your system into a server and a client. They can both run within the same application. When the application starts, it checks if there are any servers on the local network, and if there aren't, it starts one. It then connects to the server.

That's what Filemaker at least used to do 20 years ago, and it worked pretty well. Should be a breeze to implement using modern frameworks today (say Qt or boost).

Comment: You know, I'm trying to stick with C or C++ solutions and eliminate dependency on any major libraries, especially ones that come with a license fee (like Qt.) If anything, I'd go with MS SQL and .NET instead. But thanks anyway. The client/server idea might be what I need. So the search goes on...

Comment: @c0000fd Qt is free (LGPL). Boost is too. You can't develop C++ efficiently without using frameworks of some sort. Boost is a bare minimum you need to be productive. Heck, you can't even use SQLITE productively from C++ while using its C API - you need to wrap it so that you won't be writing C but C++ indeed. C++ is not C.

Comment: Last I checked, Qt could not be used for free to write commercial software.

Comment: @c00000fd You last checked 6+ years ago, then? LGPL is compatible with closed-source commercial software, even statically linked. All you need is offer a way to relink your object code with Qt that you provide the source for. DLLs delay the linking to runtime, static LIBs allow you to provide a binary blob that represents your closed-source code just like your EXE did and do the relinking prior to runtime. Easy-peasy. IANAL.